# Why is list-array loosing its value in onCreate method?

Tags: java, android

May be I am missing out on something but I am struggling with very basic problem. what I am trying to do is access some data from my database through a method `retrievedata` called on `onCreate` method and the returned list data is assigned to a listarray in it and based on the size of that list data I do some operation.

The problem is that regardless of the data returned from my database ,the arraylist return its size as zero . Here is what I tried to do in `onCreate()` method

```
              retrievedata();
    if (list_entry_model_list.size()==0)  //problem here returns true  always
        notesDatabase.listDaoClass().insert_lists(new List_Entry_Model(""));
```

the **retrievedata()** method is given below

```
             public void retrievedata() {

    listLiveData = notesDatabase.listDaoClass().load_all_lists();
    listLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<List_Entry_Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<List_Entry_Model> list_entry_models) {
            list_entry_model_list = list_entry_models;   //here I assigned data to the Listarray that I declared as class variable.

            listadapter.submitList(list_entry_model_list);

            listadapter.setData(list_entry_model_list);

        }
    });
    Log.d("yummyinside", String.valueOf(list_entry_model_list.size()));
}
```

If i retrieve size of listarray inside the `retrievedata()` method,it shows correct size .Listarray is declared as a class variable. So why is it loosing its value.

Thank you. Correct me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listLiveData.observe is an asynchronous function, so `if (list_entry_model_list.size()==0)` will get executed without waiting for result of `listLiveData.observe` i.e it will executed before anything get assigned to list_entry_model_list.

Comment: So that's the catch . Is there any handy way to get my code work as desired . ?

Comment: move insert statement inside onchanged or trigger async insert from onchanged when size is 0

Comment: Thank you ,that works .But why does it return correct size inside onChanged and not outside it  as the listarray is already initialized with returned data? @AlexanderPavlov .

Comment: onchange  happens when data are available (not when you create onchange handler) so size is correct here. your code outside onchange may be executed before data are available.